# tensorflow bazel-bin optimized_graph don't loss volume

Tags: android, tensorflow, optimization, porting

I have to do porting from tensorflow to android. 
After training, I made '.pb' file. 
For compression, I had to run

```
"bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference --input=myfile.pb --output=optimized.pb --input_names=input --output_names=output"
```

But it didn't work for 'myfile' have 258mb filesize. After optimized_graph, 'output file' still have 258mb filesize.

Let me know the solution, please.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Optimize for inference only removes useless nodes and packs operations together where possible.
What you want is to `round_weights`. This will slightly alter your network's weights to make the network more compressible (at the cost, of course, of a slight change in accuracy).

At the ["Optimizing for mobile" section of TF's website](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/optimizing) you find the details of the tool, how to use it and all the caveats that it has.

In that link you also find the explanation of why your file doesn't compress (and why it will,after rounding the weights):

> The original file does not compress well with standard algorithms,
>   because the bit patterns of even very similar numbers can be very
>   different. The round_weights transform keeps the weight parameters
>   stored as floats, but rounds them to a set number of step values. This
>   means there are a lot more repeated byte patterns in the stored model,
>   and so compression can often bring the size down dramatically, in many
>   cases to near the size it would be if they were stored as eight bit.